# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp]

Tags: xml, spring, maven, sftp

I am getting the following exception while trying to connect to the SFTP host. 
I have added the stacktrace and my configuration file settings and the dependencies which i am using for sftp.

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [app-config.xml]
Exception in thread "main"
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: 
Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for
XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp]
Offending resource: class path resource [app-config.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:316)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1421)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.canaldigital.tsi.bank.config.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:15)
```

Pom.XML

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
  <artifactId>sshd-core</artifactId>
  <version>0.10.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

App-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.canaldigital.tsi.bank" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:settings.properties" />

    <task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
        <task:scheduled ref="myBean" method="printMessage" fixed-delay="600000" initial-delay="3000"/>
        <task:scheduled ref="myBean" method="checkStatus" fixed-delay="6000" initial-delay="2000"/>
    </task:scheduled-tasks>

    <task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10" />


     <bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="defaultSftpSessionFactory" />
             <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10"/>
             <property name="sessionWaitTimeout" value="1000"/>     
    </bean>


    <bean id="defaultSftpSessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${sftp.host}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${sftp.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${sftp.password}"/>
        <property name="port" value="#{sftp.serverPort}"/>      
    </bean>

<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpAdapterAutoCreate"
            session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
            channel="requestChannel"
            filename-pattern="*.csv"
            remote-directory="/home/oracle/IBSTOBANK/DNB/Norway/Outgoing"
            preserve-timestamp="true"
            local-directory="file:target/foo"
            auto-create-local-directory="true"
            local-filename-generator-expression="#this.toUpperCase() + '.a'"
            local-filter="myFilter"
            temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
            delete-remote-files="false">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"  max-messages-per-poll="1"/>
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
    <int:channel id="requestChannel">
        <int:queue/>
    </int:channel>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be because you are missing the `spring-integration-sftp.jar` file in your `classpath`. Can you verify if this file is in the `classpath`. If it is not there add below one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-sftp</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```